# Changing zoom level steps of Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, zoom

When I zoom in Sketch by using the shortcuts [cmd +], [cmd -] or the plus and minus button the zoom factor change by 100%. (25%, 50%, 100%, 200%, 400% etc.) When I use preview I like to see my screen completely filled like I use my browser. Is there a way to change the zoom levels in Sketch preferably by percents.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find the way to change zoom factor in Sketch, but there is other many ways to work with zooming:

**Shortcuts:**
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> Center canvas
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> Zoom selection
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> Actual size
<kbd>§</kbd> Temporary Zoom to Actual Size
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> Presentation Mode
<kbd>Z</kbd>: Zoom Tool. Hold down and click or drag an area with the mouse.
 Reverse zoom using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and click.

**Plugins:**
https://github.com/arkkimaagi/artboardzoom Tiny Sketch.app plugin for zooming to Artboard of currently selected object.
http://cl.ly/0C07091e3Y3W Sketch plugin for input custom percentage of zooming

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So, to customise the percentage of zooming I have to install a plugin? I've tried to install the one you suggest for this, but it isn't working. Sketch doesn't install it automatically and the menu option: Reveal Plugins Folder doens't exist anymore. Any suggestion how to get the plugin installed? (other options like using the terminal to find the plugin location also didn't work)

Comment: @ErnstP. check please: https://www.sketchapp.com/support/developer/01-introduction/01.html

Comment: I did that and as said: the plugin didn't install automatically by double click. In the newest version of Sketch you doesn't have access to the Reveal Plugin Folder by the menu bar. The suggested folder doesn't exist. (I know how to work with the terminal)

Comment: You can zoom continuously using a trackpad.